# How to manage/close multiple db connections inside thread ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, activerecord

I have scenario where Models use different DB connections.

```
#database.yml    
development:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: dev_schema
    username: root
    password: root
    host: localhost

otherdb:
    adapter: mysql2
    database: xyz_schema
    username: root
    password: root
    host: localhost
```

Two models using above defined connections.

```
   class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
     #default uses developement connection
   end

   class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
     establish_connection :otherdb
   end
```

In one of my use case, I am manually creating thread as bellow.

```
 Thread.new do 
    begin
        Foo.last
        Bar.last
    rescue Exception => e
      raise e
    ensure
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close if ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    end
 end
```

It is observed that **ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close**, closing connection only of development not otherdb and thread under high concurrency establishing more db connections than connection pool defined in database.yml.

Is there any syntax like **Bar.connection.close** to close **otherdb** connection manually of current thread?

Comment: Hm, doesn't `Bar.connection.close` work?

Comment: Bar.connection.close seems its working, does it close otherdb connection of current thread?

Comment: I would expect so. Why don't you check this?

Comment: ok thanks for reply, I mean does it close only current thread otherdb connection or all active threads otherdb connections?